# Checking a null value in a join query after 2 joins and a where or condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query that is checking to see if a value exists, given criteria. It joins `Permits`, `AccessControlTypes`, and `EntanceEnhancementHistories`, all on their `Guid` FKs. It checks Permits of Type "Full" or "Limited" to see if they have any associated `EntranceEnhancementHistories`.

```
bool LimitedorFullEntranceEnhancementValue = (
     from p in context.Permits
     join a in context.AccessControlTypes on p.EntranceAccessControlTypeGUID equals a.GUID
     join e in context.EntranceEnhancementHistories on p.GUID equals e.PermitGUID
     where p.GUID.Equals(PermitGuid) 
       && ((a.Description.Equals("Full") || a.Description.Equals("Limited")) 
       && (e.GUID == null))
     select e).Any();
return LimitedorFullEntranceEnhancementValue;
```

This query is failing. It's returning false in the case that is does find description of full or limited, but does not find an `entrancehancementvalue` (it should be `null`).
It works properly without the check for a `null` `entranceenhancementvalue`, and I'm able to get it working with 2 queries, but I don't think this should be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an "inner join" `on p.GUID equals e.PermitGUID`, which means you'll only see results where an `e.PermitGUID` exists. I think you want something more like this:

```
 (from p in context.Permits
 join a in context.AccessControlTypes on p.EntranceAccessControlTypeGUID equals a.GUID
 where p.GUID.Equals(PermitGuid) 
   && ((a.Description.Equals("Full") || a.Description.Equals("Limited")) 
   && !context.EntranceEnhancementHistories.Any(e => p.GUID == e.PermitGUID)
 select p).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN if you expect to see rows where the Guid key is null:

```
(from p in context.Permits
 join a in context.AccessControlTypes on p.EntranceAccessControlTypeGUID equals a.GUID
 join t in context.EntranceEnhancementHistories on p.GUID equals e.PermitGUID into leftJoin
 join e in leftJoin on p.DefaultIfEmpty()
 where p.GUID.Equals(PermitGuid) 
   && ((a.Description.Equals("Full") || a.Description.Equals("Limited")) 
   && (e.GUID == null))
 select e).Any();
```

return LimitedorFullEntranceEnhancementValue;